# Eclipse PyDev won't recognize Django

Tags: python, eclipse, django

I recently got involved in a project that requires the following:

Python 3.3 or greater

Django 1.8 or greater

Eclipse as IDE with the PyDev plug-in

The part where I have a lot of trouble is the Eclipse part (obviously), but since I am the only one running linux in my team no one seems to care.

I can't get Eclipse or PyDev to recognize Django for python 3 and I don't know why or how to fix it. I installed it with pip3 because it was the easiest way and putting it in a virtual environment seemed hard to cope with Eclipse.

If you have an idea of how I can get Eclipse to recognize Django in Python 3 or how to run it from a virtual environment please let me know.

Thanks!